# How to access the "admin" object from Theming example in docs?

Tags: react-admin

The React-Admin's "[Theming](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html)" documentation uses the following line of code in some examples:

```js
        const open = useSelector(state => state.admin.ui.sidebarOpen);
```

It does not work as it is. What else needs to be done to access the "sidebarOpen" property?

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: `Property 'admin' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a TypeScript compilation error, meaning you should either disable typescript in this function:

```
const open = useSelector((state: any) => state.admin.ui.sidebarOpen);
```

or pass the correct Redux store type for a react-admin app:

```
import { ReduxState } from 'react-admin';

const open = useSelector((state: ReduxState) => state.admin.ui.sidebarOpen);
```